# How do I save a float to a file using android java?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, aide-ide

I have a simple game in which I would need to store a highscore (float) to a file and then read it next time the user goes on the app. I want it to be saved on the device, however, I have found no way to do that. How can I persist data on the device to a chosen location ?

Comment: Voted down in less than 10 seconds?

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but I can see why. Never say "I'm a noob", or "Sorry for my english" and this kind of things in a question. It adds no information

Comment: I edited your question with the minimum, relevant information (to my opinion)

Comment: OK, thanks for the info.

Comment: So which part are you having problems with? Writing to a file, reading from a file, serializing / deserializing floats? Did you read [this document](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html)?

Comment: I can't seem to even make the file. I read the document but it just gave me an "Unknown entity FileOutputStream"

Comment: You can google for `save a file android java` and get everything you could possibly need. You are getting downvoted because you put forth 0 effort to solve this on your own.

Comment: If you are writing code, put it in your question. As it stands right now it looks like have done nothing.

Comment: I've spent ages googling on my own.

Comment: Simply use the [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html). Use `putFloat()` and `getFloat()` to save and retrieve your float value, respectively.

Comment: Frank, I tried that too. I just got an error: "getSharedPreferences is undefined"

Comment: If so, you messed something up. It works; believe me.

Comment: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Preferences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use internal storage. This will create files that can be written to and read from. The best way to do this is to create a separate class that handles files. Here are two methods that will read and write the highscore.

To set the highscore, use **setHighScore(float f)**.

```
public void setHighScore(float highscore){
    FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
    try {
        outputStream = (this).openFileOutput("highscore", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        outputStream.write(Float.toString(f)).getBytes());
        outputStream.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

To get the highscore, use **getHighScore()**.

```
public float getHighScore(){
    ArrayList<String> text = new ArrayList<String>();

    FileInputStream inputStream;
    try {
        inputStream = (this).openFileInput("highscore");

        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(isr);

        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            text.add(line);
        }
        bufferedReader.close();
    } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace();}
return Float.parseFloat(text.get(1));
}
```

Comment: In my Files class I get an error: "Unknown method isEmpty of 'java.lang.string[]'"

Comment: I still get an error. See my picture that I put showing the errors http://i.stack.imgur.com/mEubi.png

Comment: @TastyTable I changed the answer completely. Put these two methods in your Activity class.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I get another error: 'Unknown method "openFileOutput"' :(

Comment: @TastyTable You are doing this in an activity, correct? You seem to be having a problem getting the context of the activity. Could you post your full code?

Comment: @TastyTable And you're welcome. This will be solved soon, and then I can get my green checkmark.

Comment: It was because it wasn't an activity

Comment: @TastyTable Only Activity's have their own context.

Answer (score 0):

**Using File Handling** - 
I would suggest going basic by using a file handling technique. Auto create a text file using the java's InputStream and OutputStream classes. Then add the float inside it. As suggested in the comments above too.

**Using properties files** - 
Refer this code - http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/

**Using a database** - 
You can go ahead and use a database which will safely store the score and make sure no one tampers with it easily. Tutorial for this - http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/

Answer (score 0):

Try simple with very few lines.

```
public void saveHighScore(File file, float highScore){
try{
Formatter out = new Formatter(file);
out.format("%f", highScore);
out.close();
}catch(IOException ioe){}
}
```